# enabling and accessing multiple comports in RHEL 6.6

Tags: rhel

I am using a motherboard with The Intel Haswell platform I have installed RHEL 6.6 in it the board is having six comports.

I am unable to access more the 2 comports. What kind of setting do I need to make in `rc.local` or `\dev\ttyS` for making all the comports work ?

All the comports are detected  and enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Are you saying 'comm ports' ?